# Mysql ERROR 2013 just delete from

Tags: mysql

I am running a real old version of MySQL (3.23.56). Everything is good, expect when I want to delete all entries of a table. I have checked query, like drop, select,update, their behaviours are correct. Even I use sql like `delete from t1 where id='5'`, I can get the right answer. But for `delete from t1` (which would delete all entries in table t1), it shows:

> ERROR 2013 at line 1: Lost connection to mysql server during query.

And mysqld restarted. Even this table has only 1 entry!

I checked the error log. It shows:

```
Number of processes running now: 0
 Fri Jul 24 13:31:00 CDT 2015
150724 13:31:10  mysqld started
/home/chenyuxi/Desktop/bugs/mysql_169/mysql-build/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections
mysqld got signal 11;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help diagnose
the problem, but since we have already crashed, something is definitely wrong
and this may fail

key_buffer_size=8388600
record_buffer=131072
sort_buffer=2097144
max_used_connections=0
max_connections=100
threads_connected=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (record_buffer + sort_buffer)*max_connections = 225791 K
bytes of memory
Hope that's ok, if not, decrease some variables in the equation
```

I try to change global variable max_allowed_packet and net_read_timeout, it seems useless.

Comment: Try to tag your question right. You're asking `MySQL` related stuff, however you tagged `SQL Server`. Also, I'd post this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you could try DELETE FROM `t1` WHERE 1

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas are you implying that MySQL is NOT a SQL server?

Comment: Yes, I am. These are two different products.